# Computer shuts down instead of hibernate

Tags: laptop

I have my laptop lid close option set to hibernate. But the computer instead keeps shutting down. How do I fix this option?

I have tried setting the hard drive turn off to never both on battery and plugged in but it keeps shutting down.

Comment: Is Hibernation enabled?

Comment: yes and fast boot is disabled

Comment: OS? Laptop model?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Windows 10, Toshiba Satellite P55W C5200X